# Forgetting how many rakat I have prayed

Tags: salat, waswasa

Assalam alaykum

I tend to have issues with memory and concentration, so during namaz I am always forgetting how many rakat I have prayed. and I am always praying more rakat than I need to.

I have taken a video of me while praying to make sure if I prayed right or not, and I always pray the correct amount of rakat.

But when I am praying, I get waswasah and end up praying extra rakat just to make sure that my prayer is valid, and so for example I would pray 5 rakat for zuhr.

Deep down I know that I am praying right but I am always getting wasasah that I haven't prayed enough rakat, so for the past year or so I have been praying extra just in case.

Please help.

Comment: "I have taken a video of me ... I always pray the correct amount of rakat." .... this is proof that your waswasa is baseless. So just ignore it. We are not a peer support group.

Comment: I also face this problem. I think that it is waswasa partially and I seek protection from Allah. However I suspect that another part of the reason is that we are humans. I tend to loose concentration and forget things while doing other tasks also.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum brother , if this continues for for years, i first recommend you to ask du'a to Allah (SWT), to protect you from waswasah(whisper) of shaytan, it happens to most of the people during salah, make sure you do 2 sajdah when u don't the count of your rakah, ask Allah to increase your concentration and protection from shaytan❤️

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).